# LinkedHashMap changes to HashMap and crashes in flink data stream operators

Tags: scala, exception, serialization, hashmap, apache-flink

Given this dummy code:

```
 1 case class MyObject(values:mutable.LinkedHashMap[String, String])

...

 2    implicit val typeInfoString:TypeInformation[String] = TypeInformation.of(classOf[String])
 3    implicit val typeInfoMyObject:TypeInformation[MyObject] = TypeInformation.of(classOf[MyObject])
 4
 5    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
 6
 7    env
 8      .fromElements("one")
 9      .map(str =>
10      {
11        val obj = MyObject(mutable.LinkedHashMap("key" -> str))
12        val filteredMap1:mutable.LinkedHashMap[String, String] = obj.values.filter(!_._2.contains("bla"))
13
14        obj
15      })
16      .map(obj =>
17      {
18        val filteredMap2:mutable.LinkedHashMap[String, String] = obj.values.filter(!_._2.contains("bla"))
19
20        obj
21      })
```

The application will crashin line 18 with the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap cannot be cast to scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap
```

The issues seems to be that through serialization/deserialization the `values` member changes its object type, or in other words, `LinkedHashMap` turns into `HashMap`.

Note that the same code as in line 18 works perfectly in line 12.

When setting a breakpoint to line 12, `obj.values` will be shown as `LinkedHashMap` by the debugger/IntelliJ, however a breakpoint in line 18 will show `obj.values` as `HashMap` in the debugger.

What is going on here? How can I fix this? After all, `LinkedHashMap` implements `Serializable`?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default Kryo Chill serializer for `LinkedHashMap` does not preserve the map type and instead deserializes the data into a `HashMap`. In order to avoid this, one needs to create a serializer for the `LinkedHashMap` type:

```
class LinkedHashMapSerializer[K, V] extends Serializer[mutable.LinkedHashMap[K, V]] with Serializable {
  override def write(kryo: Kryo, output: Output, `object`: mutable.LinkedHashMap[K, V]): Unit = {
    kryo.writeObject(output, `object`.size)

    for (elem <- `object`.iterator) {
      kryo.writeClassAndObject(output, elem._1)
      kryo.writeClassAndObject(output, elem._2)
    }
  }

  override def read(kryo: Kryo, input: Input, `type`: Class[mutable.LinkedHashMap[K, V]]): mutable.LinkedHashMap[K, V] = {
    val result = new mutable.LinkedHashMap[K, V]()
    val size = kryo.readObject(input, classOf[Int])
    for (_ <- 1 to size) {
      val key = kryo.readClassAndObject(input).asInstanceOf[K]
      val value = kryo.readClassAndObject(input).asInstanceOf[V]
      result.put(key, value)
    }

    result
  }
}
```

And then register it as a Kryo `Serializer`:

```
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
env.registerTypeWithKryoSerializer(classOf[mutable.LinkedHashMap[String, String]], new LinkedHashMapSerializer())
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. With the custom serializer it seems to work. However I am not sure what `val serializer = new TraversableSerializer ... ` is good for? It does not seem to be used.
Also, when I import `org.apache.flink.api.scala.typeutils.TraversableSerializer`, it complains about the `false` parameter (its expecting a parameter of type `TypeSerializer`).

Comment: Sorry that was not meant to be there. I've corrected the second snippet.

Comment: Okay, in fact it works for my minimal example, however it does not work with my real code. In the actual implementation `LinkedHashMap` is buried within a more complex case class structure, and running with your changes now throws a `ExceptionInChainedOperatorException` caused by a `KryoException` - it complains about "Unable to find class" (my involved case classes).
Does this mean I will have to supply custom serializers for all my involved case classes and intermediate classes now? I mean it worked before the changes.

Comment: Made some more simpler tests, and it seems like the custom serializer cannot handle nested types within the `LinkedHashMap`. It throws e.g. `com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Unable to find class: Xscala.None$`, and seemlingy for just any non-POJO type involved.

Comment: I've updated the `Serializer` implementation once more to use `kryo.writeClassAndObject` instead of `kryo.writeObject`. I hope this works now.